QGIS 3.22.16 Roads not centered on the background
I am working on QGIS 3.22.16. I offset -3 for the right lane layer and leave 0 for the left lane layer. So the lanes don't overlap. However, the lines don't seem to follow the background routes. Is there a way to center those lines on the background routes.

where did you get the road centre lines from?
